# HTTPS POST Request from server to rpi-nodejs thru linksys router

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi2

Im trying to connect: Google Home device -> API.AI Webhook -> RPi/nodejs but the API.AI webhook requires an https URL. Ive tried Hurl.it to POST to the http url of my router and setup up port forwarding to make the request reach the rpi and I can see the post come in from the terminal running nodejs which responds appropriately to the request.

But when I change the Hurl.it to https:// url, change the port forwarding of the router to rout 443 requests to the same rpi address and change the .env port for the nodejs app listening on 80 to 443...if I run the POST request, the router log records the https request but the nodejs app does not respond, it just keeps listening on port 443.  Here is a link to the app.js:

[KylesAppjsCode](https://github.com/quique123/aismarthome/blob/master/app.js)

How do I figure out why the nodejs server app isnt getting the request or if its receiving it then why is it not responding to the request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`app.listen()` currently always uses http](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/c087a45b9cc3eb69c777e260ee880758b6e03a40/lib/application.js#L617) and never https, so you will need to create your own custom https server and pass `app` as the request handler:

```
require('https').createServer({ /* https config */ }, app)
                .listen(process.env.PORT, function() {
  console.log('Listening on port ' + process.env.PORT);
});
```

instead of:

```
app.listen(process.env.PORT, function() {
  console.log('Listening on port ' + process.env.PORT);
});
```

Comment: Can I "create" that server with nginx?  Im not sure how to do it but I got that suggestion elsewhere.

Comment: You can set it up however you want, there are tutorials galore online. However, for this particular problem as-is, you will need to call `https.createServer()` yourself.

Comment: Ok I finally installed and configured nginx. But I get an `Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::443` upon running sudo npm start.  Note that the original http post to my routers ip (forwarded to rpinodejs lan ip) was successful & the https://subdomain.domain.com request of a dummy html page on nginx was also successful.

Comment: I've posted about it here: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=91&t=181305